# Windows phone 8 and phonegap 2.7.0, Navigation between HTML pages and Xaml and back

Tags: c#, javascript, cordova, windows-phone-8

I am developing an app, that will have a separate camera functionality. The reason is I do not like phonegap's builit in getPicture for windows phone as it automatically saves the image on the user's device, which will chew up alot of memory.

How my app currently works,

user opens app, app directs them to login.html page (where they enter username/pass) then to menu.html where they have a number of different options/features one of them is a take picture button, which opens camera.html in camera.html page i have this, code which calls my seperate Echo.cs class/plugin tool

```
        cordova.exec(function (imageData) { onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData); }, function (err) {
            alert("Intent Error. Unable to call update routines");
        }, "Echo", "takePicture", ["takepicture"]);
```

my takePicture method looks like this:

```
    public void takePicture(string options)
    {
        string takePic = null;
        Debug.WriteLine("Reached imageconvert method");
        try
        {
            string[] data = JsonHelper.Deserialize<string[]>(options);
            takePic = data[0];


        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("ERROR OCCURED!");
            DispatchCommandResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.JSON_EXCEPTION));
            return;
        }


        if ((takePic != null) && (takePic.Length > 0))
        {
            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                (Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame).Navigate(new Uri("/Camera.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

                //logic here some way to get the image back from camera.xaml and resume my currant page.
            });


            //DispatchCommandResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, "imaged passed back from camera.xaml should go here"));
        }
        else
        {
            DispatchCommandResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.ERROR, "Expected one non-empty string argument."));
            return;
        }
    }
```

this code above, redirects the user to a seperate camera.xaml page I built where my custom camera processes an image without saving it to the user library and converts it to encoded 64basestring to send back as ImageData, My question now is, is there a way to send that ImageData information back some how and resume my app from Camera.html page? is this even possible with phonegap?

Comment: were u able to solve the above problem?

Answer (score 0):

i have used to back:

```
DispatchCommandResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, "imaged passed back from   camera.xaml should go here"));
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
    root = Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame;
    root.GoBack();
});
```

if you use root.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative)); will lost the actual page and return to index

sorry my english